# too much reliance on localStorage?

Tags: html, local-storage

I'm building a demo, and find that I am storing lots of data in localStorage, almost constantly writing and reading values, parsing and stringifying JSON, etc. etc.

Do you find yourself relying on localStorage much?

What are the dangers of overusing it?
Are there dangers in regularly translating variables from and to JSON for storage?

It seems to me that if I did a db storage of lots of this data, I'd significantly increase the number and size of queries to my db.

The demo is very user focused, so I'm storing stuff like items the user has selected and input the user has provided. The data stored locally is only of value/interest to the user.

If you were building something like a todo list with scheduled end dates and reminders, would you use localStorage? Why or why not?

I know one limitation is that the user would only be able to view this content on one browser on one machine, but that isn't an issue for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really only write data to local storage that should persist across pages. If you're constantly parsing/stringifying JSON, then your code is likely much slower than it needs to be. Aside from reducing performance, there's a limited amount of space available in local storage, so you should use it judiciously.

Ask yourself: *"How much of this data needs to stick around after the user leaves this page?"*

Comment: Thanks Matt, I just added a bit to the question about creating something like an advanced todo list, as that is very similar to what i'm doing. I think I disagree with your comment re: after the user leaves the page, as I think that part of the value is to allow the user to load existing data on a new page. Like a shopping cart or something. Why re-query the db when the user goes to the checkout?
Also, the limitations on memory are 5mb, so I think that is a significant amount of JSON, I can't imagine using 1/2 that.

Comment: I agree that localStorage is a reasonable alternative to re-querying the database. My answer boils down to this: store as little as you need to in localStorage. Your question is quite vague, however, so it's impossible to definitively say whether or not you're misusing localStorage.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I was purposely vague aiming for two goals 1) what sort of guidelines should be used for using localStorage - not only in this project but in future use 2) I figure the more vague I was, the best answer would be provided for other users.